# How I can allow a user to modify only their data in django rest framework?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a Location model that only should be modified by the owner

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
```

This is the API Location Serializer

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('user', 'name', 'address',)
```

The problem is that I want the user be the *request user*

Actually I overwrite the create method of viewset but I think that is not the best solution

```
class LocationViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                mixins.ListModelMixin,
                GenericViewSet):
    model = Location
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.DATA.copy()
        data.update({'user':unicode(self.request.user.id)})

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data, files=request.FILES)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.pre_save(serializer.object)
            self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
            self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: you have this `def get_queryset(self): return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)` it already show to the user only his data. do i miss something?
i didn't get what's the probem.
If you want to change data before storing them, extend `pre_save()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to adapt the [example from the tutorial about associating snippets with users](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users). Keep your `get_queryset` implementation and then set the `user` field to the request user in `pre_save`.

Comment: example doesn't define user as a related field. it only uses username, I wonder how would serialzer.is_valid() act when it does try to validate user field.